# How customize a class to django admin?

Tags: django

Hello I like to put a custom class in my django admin, overwrite default update, but i can't

```
class Aprovacao(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tipo = None
        self.nome = None
        self.data = None


class ServicoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'descricao', 'porcentagem']
    search_fields = ['id', 'descricao']


class PavimentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'descricao']
    search_fields = ['id', 'descricao']


class AprovacaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['tipo']


admin.site.register(Servico, ServicoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Pavimento, PavimentoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Aprovacao, AprovacaoAdmin)
```

Why?

Comment: Er, what? The admin is to manage the entries in your database. What are you trying to do with Aprovacao?

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic class to put in django admin, like tipo could be Servico descricao or Aprovacao Descricao